# Is there a way to fit bar plots into my Graph using Plotly and Dash?

Tags: plotly-dash, plotly-python

I started playing with Dash and Plotly recently so I did my first bar plot. However, there is one thing that I want to change but I couldn't find a way to do so. Currently, when I start my Dash app and go to my localhost url, I have the following graph:
[image]

After a double-click on the plot, I get the following zoomed graph:
[image]

Is there a way to make my graph look like my second image by default or to have the width of the plots to be `fit-content`? I did a research and it seems that I can set `xrange` and `yrange` but I have a dynamic graph and sometimes I can have 8 plots, sometimes I can have 18 plots and approximating the `xrange` won't be that useful for my case.

Comment: Note `autorange=True` is set by default on the (plotly figure) axes, which makes the `xrange` and `yrange` automatically fit the input data (ie. the result should be what you expect by default, unless specified otherwise), so there is probably an issue with the data you provide to `px.bar()` or `go.Bar()` or with the figure's layout settings, but we can't guess.. You will need to provide the relevant code so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I did manage to fix my issue, it was with my layout settings as you said.